# Linq update with specific select of column being null

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to select few columns from SQl and then update that table.

I used

```
 var xyz_repl= from mfrepl in xyz_repl_alias
               where (mfrepl.RPT_ID == sched_data.NOTIF_RPT_ID) 
               && (mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == "" || mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == null)
               select mfrepl;
```

This did my job but then it does not work if any column is NULL.Then I tried to select only specific column but now they become readonly and I am not able to **update** the table.

I did this :

```
var xyz_repl= from mfrepl in xyz_repl_alias
              where (mfrepl.RPT_ID == sched_data.NOTIF_RPT_ID) 
              && (mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == "" || mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == null)
              select new 
                    {
                     mfrepl.NOTIF_ID,
                     mfrepl.REPL_DTM,
                     mfrepl.REPL_TYPE,
                     mfrepl.RPT_ID,
                     mfrepl.RPT_VERS 
                    } ;
```

**NOTE**- It is now showing as anonymous type.What I need to do?Any suugestion.

**UPDATE**
I added one more class  i.e. :

```
public class MyPoco
    {
        public string NOTIF_ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime REPL_DTM { get; set; }
        public string REPL_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string  RPT_ID { get; set; }
        public string RPT_VERS { get; set; }

    }
```

and changed my code to

```
var xyz_repl = from mfrepl in xyz_repl_alias 
where (mfrepl.RPT_ID == sched_data.NOTIF_RPT_ID) && (mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == "" || mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == null)
select new MyPoco {
NOTIF_ID=mfrepl.NOTIF_ID,
 REPL_DTM=mfrepl.REPL_DTM,
 REPL_TYPE=mfrepl.REPL_TYPE,
 RPT_ID=mfrepl.RPT_ID, 
RPT_VERS=mfrepl.RPT_VERS };
```

But now

```
   db.SubmitChanges(); is not working.It won`t update databse now.Any suggestion.
```

Comment: If your database columns are nullable, then your corresponding class types should be nullable also. This will prevent the issue so you don't have to select into an anonymous type.

Comment: @mattytommo I added CanBeNull =true but no use.I do not want to get all columns because many columns are useless in later program and contains large data.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you: Inside `new`, you can control nullable fields and give them a default value. For one field inside `new` for example: `REPL_DTM =  mfrepl.REPL_DTM == null ? false : mfrepl.REPL_TYPE;`

Comment: Linq To What? What are you using?

Comment: @Aron Linq to SQl Sir

Comment: @mggSoft It is still readonly.I want to select few columns andthen update the table

Comment: I have removed that column itself from Model.It is working now..but still I want to know the alternative to clear my concepts.Will keep this question open for some time for any expert to comment and help me understanding.

Comment: `xyz_repl_alias` is what you need to create a double of. The problem is not the anonymous type, the problem is the type which isn't part of the context.

Comment: @flindeberg yes Sir,exactly.But how do I overcome this.How to make mypoco or xyz_repl  as part of current context?

Comment: You have access to the context? That is where you need to make the changes. It is a new question though. Please create a new question about "table splitting, datacontext and LINQ2SQL". And maybe read http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting if you haven't? (It's for entity framework, but the essence is there)

Comment: @flindeberg Got the idea,but still not able to create custom datacontext object.Not finding proper online tutorial for linq to sql Custom data context.Between thanks a lot.Marking your answer but will go via my workaround and will try to learn about tablesplit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that your model is not identical to you database, if you could select the row directly (you said `Linq2SQL` and not `Linq2Entities`) then you could update it again, which you do.

If you select an anonymous type then you lose the context connection and cannot use the `SubmitChanges()` since it is not tracked by the context.

One of the problems with most real world implementations is that the database must match the model to make it work properly, is using `Linq2SQL` and `Linq2Entities` against legacy databases usually makes you run into trouble like this.

If the rows are to big, as you are implying in the comments, I would define a new model "table" which only selects a subset of the columns, and use that one to update the rows.

(I'm using the term `row` to differ from `entity` in `Linq2Entities` since I do not know the proper term in `Linq2SQL`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. But I mapped them .My Sql Schema looks like     **REPL_GUID varchar,**
**REPL_TYPE varchar,**
**RPT_ID varchar,**
**RPT_VERS varchar,**
**RPT_BYTES bigint,**
**REPL_DTM datetime,**
**NOTIF_ID varchar ,**   and same I made in Model class.  Now,In order to solve my problem,I have removed the column from Model but this is just a workaround(not good one).

Comment: Use two tables in model, as I stated, one for the entire table in database and one for the selection of columns you need for this particular scenario.

Comment: Ok.I changed and new code is like : **var Mainframe_replication_value = from mfrepl in mainframe_replication_alias
                                                          where (mfrepl.RPT_ID == sched_data.NOTIF_RPT_ID) && (mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == "" || mfrepl.NOTIF_ID == null)

                                                          select new MyPoco {NOTIF_ID=mfrepl.NOTIF_ID, REPL_DTM=mfrepl.REPL_DTM, REPL_TYPE=mfrepl.REPL_TYPE, RPT_ID=mfrepl.RPT_ID, RPT_VERS=mfrepl.RPT_VERS }** But now I am not able to update the table.db.submitchange() have no impact on this

Comment: @v2v2 It is very hard to follow in comments, could you update your question?